# How to access functions from ModelAdmin in template?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Lets assume a `ConactAdmin` for showing a `ConactModel`:

```
class ContactAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

  change_form_template = "admin/contact_change.html"

  def my_custom_fnc():
    return "Test"
```

Now I want to access `my_custom_fnc()` in an view html my `contact_change` template like `<p>{{my_custom_fnc()}}</p>`

Is there a list of properties which I can access in my own template? I couldn't find it in the documentation.

Comment: Are you trying to calculate some value from the current instance state to display in the admin?

Answer (score 0):

The current modeladmin instance is available in the context as `adminform.model_admin` so this should work (nb : no parens - this is the Django template language, not Python) :

```
<p>{{ adminform.model_admin.my_custom_fnc }}</p>
```

This being said, depending on what `my_custom_func` is supposed to do, there might be better solutions...

NB : to find out what you have in a template context, you can use the `{% debug %}` template tag. Also, Django is OSS so you can just read the source code (which is what I did here).

Comment: I tried with my sample above but "Test" isn't printed out. You said there are better ways. Like calculating the return value before?

Comment: As I stated, this __should__ work ;-) - at least with Django 1.x, things might have changed in 2.x, but I also hinted you on how to find out what's available in a template context. wrt/ the "better ways", it really depends on what you're method is really supposed to do, but yes computing the value and passing it in the `extra_context` of the `change_view` method is one possible solution. In all cases, the source code is, ultimately, the most reliable documentation (even if not always the easiest to understand).